# Decoding strings in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, urldecode, string-decoding

I have an app that works with some texts and I need to decode strings like:

> example\x27s string
>
> example\u0027s string

For the first one I tried using `Uri.UnescapeDataString(string.Replace("\\x", "%"))` which works but not always because if the string is something like "*the 40% of somethings's stuff*", it throws an `Exception` because of the "40%".

For the second one I don't really know how to decode that.

Is there something I can use to decode those two kind of strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(input);
```

Results:

```
"example\x27s string" -> "example's string"
"example\u0027s string" -> "example's string"
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx).